# Question tags negative or positive

Tags: negation, tag-questions

How can we ask a question tag for the following questions? Negative or positive?

> The boys problems are physical not mental,...?

> They were warned not to climb the mountain in such bad weather, ...?

Is it correct to use negative question tag?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a tag is to check for agreement.  In the first case I simply wouldn't tag at the end but split into two sentences.  Then there are two alternatives.

> The boy's problems are physical, aren't they? They aren't mental.

> The boy's problems are physical.  They aren't mental, are they?

The second has a clear positive verb and so the tag would normally be negative.  The negative verb in the infinitive clause is not being questioned.

> They *were* warned not to climb the mountain in such bad weather, weren't they?

I've also stressed the verb "were", as would be natural, if this was in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

For the first time you can ask

> The boys problems are physical not mental, are they not?/aren't they?

you say it with a negative "aren't they" confirming if they really are or not, for the second one you can say

> They were warned not to climb the mountain in such bad weather, were they not?/weren't they?

which basically points out that the asker makes it certain "They were warned about it, right?"

Answer (score 0):

There are several uses for the tag in a tag question.

1. To convert the foregoing statement into a question
2. To ask a rhetorical question following a statement
3. To ask a genuine question following a statement
4. To challenge a statement

For the first three above, the tag must always be positive in contrast to a negative statement, or negative in contrast to a positive statement.

For example:

[Neg. -> Pos.] "They **didn't** go, **did** they?"

[Pos. -> Neg.] "He **will** be there, **won't** he?"

For the challenge tag, *both sides* must be positive.

For example:

[Pos. -> Pos.] "So, you **will** skip school today, **will** you?" (Challenging)

The modal verbs or helping/auxiliary verbs are made positive or negative (via an adverb) according to their type.

| Type | Positive | Negative | Negative Contraction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Modal | can | cannot | can't |
| Modal | could | could not | couldn't |
| Modal | will | will not | won't |
| Modal | would | would not | wouldn't |
| Modal | shall | shall not | shan't |
| Modal | should | should not | shouldn't |
| Modal | may | may not | mayn't |
| Modal | might | might not | mightn't |
| Modal | must | must not | mustn't |
| Modal | need | need not | needn't |
| Being | is | is not | isn't |
| Being | am | am not | aren't |
| Being | are | are not | aren't |
| Being | was | was not | wasn't |
| Being | were | were not | weren't |
| Helping | has | has not | hasn't |
| Helping | have | have not | haven't |
| Helping | had | had not | hadn't |
| Helping | do | do not | don't |
| Helping | does | does not | doesn't |
| Helping | did | did not | didn't |

Note that in all cases, the portion of the tag to be made negative **must** be one of these verbs which has a *contracted* form--and the *same* verb.  If it cannot be made into a contraction, it is a lexical verb, and must have a helping verb added to the tag.

For example:

"He likes ice cream, **doesn't** he?"

"She got all A's in school, **didn't** she?"

"They moved away, **did** they **not**?"

[**INCORRECT**] "He has taught in your class, **isn't** it?" (Mismatched verbs: has <-> is)

Be careful of "to have."  It can function as either a *lexical* verb, or as a *helping* verb.  If it is helping, use it in the tag.  If not, use "do."

For example:

"You have a textbook, **don't** you?"  ("Have" is the primary verb; use of "haven't" in the tag is outmoded.)

"You have taken that class, **haven't** you?" ("Taken" is the lexical verb, and "have" is helping.)

In both of the example questions presented in the OP, the statements are positive (as indicated by the verbs), so, unless the intent is to ask a challenge question, the tags should be negative, following the rules described here.

**Exceptions:** There are other ways of making a tag, such as simply saying "right?" or "correct?" or "true?"  If the tag has no verb, there is no need to match the verb of the statement.  Some will also use a "tag" that presents its own complete clause, e.g. "They climbed the mountain, *isn't that true?*" This is not really just a tag anymore, but rather a grammatically complete question containing the verb's own object or complement, which is why it seems to break the rules.